# how to send message to kafka topic protected with SSL

Tags: java, ssl, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

Can anyone please suggest which properties we need to set to send message to SSL protected kafka topic using java KafkaProducer ,am new to kafka , not able to send one message to kafka protected with SSL

Answer (score 15):

I assume you already know how to configure Kafka for SSL. You need to add configuration settings for SSL encryption and for SSL authentication. Basically, this is a basic producer structure for that.

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");

//configure the following three settings for SSL Encryption
props.put(CommonClientConfigs.SECURITY_PROTOCOL_CONFIG, "SSL");
props.put(SslConfigs.SSL_TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION_CONFIG, "/var/private/ssl/kafka.client.truststore.jks");
props.put(SslConfigs.SSL_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD_CONFIG,  "test1234");

// configure the following three settings for SSL Authentication
props.put(SslConfigs.SSL_KEYSTORE_LOCATION_CONFIG, "/var/private/ssl/kafka.client.keystore.jks");
props.put(SslConfigs.SSL_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD_CONFIG, "test1234");
props.put(SslConfigs.SSL_KEY_PASSWORD_CONFIG, "test1234");

props.put(ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG, "all");
props.put(ProducerConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG, 0);
props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");

Producer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<String, String>(props);
TestCallback callback = new TestCallback();
Random rnd = new Random();
for (long i = 0; i < 100 ; i++) {
   ProducerRecord<String, String> data = new ProducerRecord<String, String>(
           "test-topic", "key-" + i, "message-"+i );
   producer.send(data, callback);
}

producer.close();
```

Comment: Hello, How can i use these all in c#?

Comment: This is exactly what I did and yet I am stuck with ssl handshake errors. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49269261/enabling-ssl-on-kafka